# Using find and substr to remove a comma from my output

Tags: c++

I messaged my instructor for assistance with my cin.ignore and this is what she messaged me back. The problem is that when you read in last – it includes the comma. So your cin.ignore needs 2 arguments, 100, \n. In this case, you don’t need the cin.ignore. Just read in first and then middle. Then use string functions to “find” the comma and create a substring from last starting at position 0 to the place before the comma. The problem is I have no idea what she is talking about. I know how to put in a find function but the second part I am not getting.  so I have put the find and substr in my program clearly not working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char chr;
int main()
{
    string last, first, middle;

    cout << "Enter in this format your Last name comma First name Middle name.    " << endl;
    // Input full name in required format
    last.find(",");
    last.substr(0);
    cin >> last;

    // receiving the input Last name 
    cin >> first;
    // receiving the input First name
    cin >> middle;
    // receiving the input Middle name
    cout << first << " " << middle << " " << last;
    // Displaying the inputed information in the format First Middle Last name

    cin >> chr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the format fixed as `Miller, John Henry` or could it also be `Miller,John Henry` (no spaces) or `Miller , John Henry` (space on both sides of the comma)? The position and number of spaces matter if you are going to tackle the problem this way.

Comment: It's probably best to read the whole line with `getline` split it at the comma, then trim any extra whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some basic misunderstandings here.

Neither `last.find(",");` nor `last.substr(0);` will do anything on their own. They both return a result, but if you don't assign it to anything, that result is lost. Moreover, `substr` takes two arguments. If you omit the second one, `last.substr(0)` will simply return all of `last`.

What your instructor meant is probably `last = last.substr( 0, last.find(",") );`. Note that this has to happen *after* you read the string from `cin`. Let's take this statement apart:

- `last.find(",")` will return the position where the comma is
- `last.substr( 0, last.find(",") )` is the part of `last` before the comma
- finally, the assignment `last = ...` will make sure that `last` actually gets changed.

Note that this only works if the comma is attached directly to the last name (as in `"Miller, John Henry"`).

Comment: how about characters after the first comma found by find(",") ? Should those characters be part of some name ?

Comment: That fixed my problem and gave me a better understanding of what I am doing Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think this is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Read a line from stdin
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    vector<string> str_vec;                                                                                                                                                          
    boost::split(str_vec, line, boost::is_any_of(" ,"));
    if (str_vec.size() == 3) {
        string last = str_vec[0];
        string first = str_vec[1];
        string middle = str_vec[2];
        std::cout << "First=" << first << " Last=" << last << " Middle=" << middle << endl;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use (or don't have) boost libraries, you can check the below version instead. The comments should help you understand each block of the code.

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                  
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Read a line from stdin
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    // Erase all commas
    while (true) {
        size_t comma_pos = line.find(",");
        if (comma_pos != std::string::npos) {
            line.erase(comma_pos, 1);
            line.insert(comma_pos, " ");
        }
        else break;
    }

    // Change all two spaces to only one space
    while (true) {
        size_t space_pos = line.find("  ");
        if (space_pos != std::string::npos)
            line.erase(space_pos, 2);
        else break;
    }

    // Tokenize the names
    size_t end_last_pos = line.find(" ");
    if (end_last_pos == string::npos) {
        cout << "Missing last name" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    string last = line.substr(0, end_last_pos);

    size_t end_first_pos = line.find(" ", end_last_pos + 1);
    if (end_first_pos == string::npos) {
        cout << "Missing first name" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    string first = line.substr(end_last_pos + 1, end_first_pos - end_last_pos - 1);

    size_t end_middle_pos = line.find(" ", end_first_pos + 1);
    string middle;
    if (end_middle_pos == string::npos)
        middle = line.substr(end_first_pos + 1);
    else
        middle = line.substr(end_first_pos + 1, end_middle_pos - end_first_pos - 1);

    // Print the names
    std::cout << "First='" << first << "' Last='" << last << "' Middle='" << middle << "'" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you could try put your

```
last.find(",");
last.substr(0);
```

After your cin ?

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't make a difference.